# How do I get the information about the selected node in the Google Charts Org Chart widget?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I have a chart rendered via the Google Charts Org Chart API.  How do I get the data about the selected node when a user clicks on a node.  I understand it to the point where I make the "getSelection" call to output selection information to the Javascript console:

```
 console.log(chart.getSelection());
```

When I look in the Chrome Javascript console, I can see the object (see below), but it doesn't show any attributes of the node in the chart.  It only shows row and column.  Is there another call to get the actual attributes of the node (like the name, etc)?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should call `chart.getSelection()`, not `this.`, because in your function `this` refers to `window`, and thus you call `window.getSelection()` that returns an unrelated object.

Here is the complete example how to get chart selection: 
[Google Charts. Interacting With the Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_interactivity)

The correct code from the link above, where `chart` and `data` refer to global variables:

```
var selectedItem = chart.getSelection()[0];
if (selectedItem) {
    var selectedValue = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
    console.log('The user selected ' + selectedValue);
}
```

Comment: You need to test the length of the array returned by `getSelection` before accessing any elements, as it is possible for the array to be empty if the user deselects an element.

Comment: @asgallant An empty array returns `undefined` if to access its [0] index. It doesn't throw exceptions.

Comment: Right, I just figured out that I need to call "chart.getSelection".  Now I'm to the point where this only returns a row and a column, but no other properties.  How do I get the various properties of the node?

Comment: @vorrtex: right, but `undefined` is rarely a valid input to anything else one might be expecting to do with the selection data.

Comment: @GregH Find where you have your chart data, something like `var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([...]);` or `var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();` and call `data.getValue` from that variable.

Comment: I am seeing only a "0" from the chart.getSelection() itself.  The event fires but but the getSelection returns simply ["0"].

Comment: Hard to answer after 3 years, Google might have updated the chart library and changed functions. So it worked for the charts which existed in 2014 but might not work for the most recent version.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.
`chart` is the instance of your chart and `data` is the container of your data (a google DataTable instance), composed in the page or fetched via ajax.
Once you get the current selection object with `chart.getSelection()` you are able to query your dataset with the current row position `data.getValue(row, col)`, to obtain the corresponding record.
`showCurrentDetailCard()` is a custom function that i use to display the details of the current node.

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
function selectHandler() {
    var selection = chart.getSelection();
    if (selection.length > 0) {
        var c = selection[0];
        showCurrentDetailCard(data.getValue(c.row, 0));
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.